# Reason of variation in sizes of fractions?

Tags: fractions, size

```
\sqrt{1 + \left( \tfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right)^2 + \left(\tfrac{\partial z}{\partial y} \right)^2}
```

The code above resulted in the second fraction being bigger than the first.

Why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your fractions are different sizes simply because "x" and "y" are not the same size: "y" is taller. Because you use `\left` and `\right`, the size of the parentheses adapt to their content, so the second pair gets bigger than the first one. This can be confirmed by `\smash`ing the "y" and adding a `\vphantom{x}` to use the height of "x" in both fractions, which I did in the second example here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt{1 + \left( \tfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right)^2 + \left(\tfrac{\partial z}{\partial y} \right)^2}
\qquad
\sqrt{1 + \left( \tfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right)^2 + \left(\tfrac{\partial z}{\partial \smash{y}\vphantom{x}} \right)^2}
\]
\end{document}
```

As @Sebastiano recommended, the best solution is probably to use `\bigl( ... \bigr)` (or similar commands) rather than `\left( ... \right)`.

Comment: +1. Instead of `\smash{y}\vphantom{x}`, though, you might write `\smash[b]{y}`.

Comment: Thank you very much to have cited my name :-)....Vincent you're better at explaining than to me :-) and I'm happy about that. Greetings.

Comment: @Mico True, it would indeed be simpler, thanks for pointing it out. I just thought it would be good to add the height of "x" explicitly.

Answer (score 15):

I am not an expert but in my humble opinion the problem will be `\left(`... `\right)` which does not give a right size, sometimes, to the formula into the rounded brackets. I have used instead `\bigl(` and `\bigr)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\[\sqrt{1 + \bigl(\tfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} \bigr)^2 + \bigl(\tfrac{\partial z}{\partial y} \bigr)^2}\]
\end{document}
```